# Retrieve users http data in repository service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, repository

I am currently building an application where each user has an unique key stored in the users' session storage. This key is used to decrypt the users data in the database. Since the repository layer of the application handles database queries (using Dapper) I would like the decryption to take place there.

Now the problem: I can retrieve the users key from the session storage, pass it to the controller, then to the service then to the repository using a parameter of name "key" in each method that is chained. Is there a way to pass a key from the controller through to the repository layer without having to include the key manually in every call?

If there is a better solution than to store it in session storage I am open to it, if it is going to make this easier.

The encryption system I am following is as follows (from another SO answer):
[image: Encryption mechanism]

Comment: What's your framework? Which version?

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimpour .Net Core 3.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can inject `IHttpContextAccessor` in your repository or other related business services to retrieve user key.

Suppose you send user key in `Header` of Http requests as `UserKey`:

In your Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    ...
}
```

In your Repository:

```
public Repository(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, ...)
{
    ...
    var userKey = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["UserKey"].FirstOrDefault();

    // Or if you send it as cookie: 
    // var userKey = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["UserKey"];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Didn't even think of this. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

Of course you could do it like in accepted answer, but still i would not recommend it

I assume you have some assembly like `ProjectName.Repositories` or `ProjectName.DAL` where all of your repositories are
To use `IHttpContextAccessor` there you should install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` as a dependency

So now your repository level knows about "what framework we are using to work with requests" and it uses current `HttpContext` to get some data

But to provide low coupling between components we should not depend on details like this

So we could write some user-defined container class to transfer `UserKey` to our repository level

there is code for my suggestion :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddScoped<UserKeyContainer>();
    services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
    ...
}
```

somewhere in the Abstraction or Dto layer you'll have

```
public class UserKeyContainer
{
    public string UserKey { get; set; }
}
```

controller code :

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserKeyContainer _keyContainer;
    private readonly IUserRepository _repository;
    public UserController(UserKeyContainer keyContainer, IUserRepository repository)
    {
        _keyContainer = keyContainer;
        _repository = repository;
    }

    [HttpGet("")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        _keyContainer.UserKey = "dasdasd"; //you should get UserKey from request there
        _repository.SomeMethod();
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

and repository :

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly UserKeyContainer _keyContainer;
    public UserRepository(UserKeyContainer keyContainer)
    {
        _keyContainer = keyContainer;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var key = _keyContainer.UserKey;
    }
}
```

Also you could use action filters to intercept requests and set `HttpContext` data to `UserKey`

Comment: This sounds more right when it comes to de-coupling. The question I have is, how would one go about invalidating the ```_keyContainer``` once the user ends the session? Or will the scoped lifetime automatically end when the user ends the session.

Comment: @Tachyon it should be PerRequest scope by default

Comment: AddScoped() - This method creates a Scoped service. A new instance of a Scoped service is created once per request within the scope. For example, in a web application it creates 1 instance per each http request but uses the same instance in the other calls within that same web request. @Tachyon

Comment: So the ```_keyContainer``` will still be relying on the Session storage to populate the session data, since it needs to persist throughout the users session? This is just adding an extra layer between the session data and the data repository for de-coupling?

Comment: @Tachyon in fact - yes. I think this is better in terms of design. Still. To populate UserKey for all User requests - ActionFilter should be implemented (my last sentence in the answer). I could impove my answer by adding its implementation if you want